# How does Cucumber resolve environment variables within profiles?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I run Cucumber with Ruby with a cucumber.yml like this:

```
profile1: env_var=value1 env_var=value2
profile2: env_var=value3
```

When I start cucumber with the first profile:

```
cucumber -p profile1
```

then "env_var" will be "value2", i.e. the last setting wins.

However when I run cucumber with both profiles:

```
cucumber -p profile1 -p profile2
```

then "env_var" will still be "value2", i.e. the second profile does not seem to override the environment variable if it was already set in the first profile.

This is certainly an exceptional use case, but I have it currently in my project, and I could not find anything in the documentation. Is this behaviour expected? My expectation would be to see env_var=value3.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Have a look at the Cucumber docs: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/configuration/#environment-variables?

Comment: Thanks, I had actually seen this beforehand. Unfortunately, it does not specify what happens if the same variable is set multiple times.

Comment: Ah, sorry I can't help you there as I don't know Ruby. You could try help channel for Ruby on the Cucumber Slack? (get an account here: https://cucumberbdd-slack-invite.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: have you tried `cucumber -p profile2 -p profile1`?

Comment: Yes I did: in this case `profile2` will win.

Comment: In the meantime I have accepted that fact that my case is too exceptional. I'm going to reorganize such that there is no overlap between the profiles. 
Thanks for the help provided.